# jq | use output from one command as input for another command

Tags: gzip, jq

So I have the file **employees.gz** which is a stream of objects:

```
{
   "name": "Billy",
   "age": 43,
   "team": "Payments",
   "id": 12345 
}
{  
   "name": "Matt",
   "age": 29,
   "team": "Payments",
   "id": 54321 
}
{  
   "name": "Jose",
   "age": 23,
   "team": "Data Center",
   "id": 89110 
} ...
```

I have another file **addresses.gz** which is also a stream of objects:

```
{
    "id": "12345",
    "name": "Billy",
    "age": 43,
    "workHistoryInState": {
      "primaryOffice": {
        "address": {
          "STREET": "1329 Prescott",
          "STATE": "CA",
          "ZIP": 97780,
          "YEARSSPENT": 19
        }
      },
      "secondaryOffice": {
        "address": {
          "STREET": "1281 Fremont",
          "STATE": "CA",
          "ZIP": "15661",
          "YEARSSPENT": 2
        }
      }, ...
    },
    "workHistoryOutOfState": {
      "primaryOffice": {
        "address": {
          "STREET": "1366 Emerson",
          "STATE": "MA",
          "ZIP": 91240,
          "YEARSSPENT": 5
        }
      },
      "secondaryOffice": {
        "address": {
          "STREET": "11 Crescent",
          "STATE": "MD",
          "ZIP": "44567",
          "YEARSSPENT": 7
        }
      }, ...
    },
    "openToRemoteWork": no,
    ...
}
{
    "id": "54321",
    "name": "Matt",
    "count": 29,
    "workHistoryInState": {
      "primaryOffice": {
        "address": {
          "STREET": "920 Rainier",
          "STATE": "WA",
          "ZIP": 98004,
          "YEARSSPENT": 3
        }
      },
      "secondaryOffice": {
        "address": {
          "STREET": "2141 7th",
          "STATE": "WA",
          "ZIP": 67812,
          "YEARSSPENT": 4
        }
      }, ...
    },
    "workHistoryOutOfState": {
      "primaryOffice": {
        "address": {
          "STREET": "56 Toll",
          "STATE": "MA",
          "ZIP": 01602,
          "YEARSSPENT": 6
        }
      },
      "secondaryOffice": {
        "address": {
          "STREET": "8th Canal",
          "STATE": "GA",
          "ZIP": 67812,
          "YEARSSPENT": 2
        }
      }, ...
    },
    "openToRemoteWork": yes,
    ...
} ...
```

Essentially, I want to retrieve the **ID** of an employee above age *25* that is on the *Payments* team that has spent the *most* **years** working at their **primary** office **in-state** and is *open* to remote work. In the example above, assuming Billy and Matt are the only employees in the database, it would be *Matt* since he meets all the criteria, hence his **ID** *54321* would be returned as the final output.

The first command returns a list of **id**s of employees that are over *25* years old and are on the *Payments* team:

```
zcat employees.gz | jq -s 'map(select(.age > 25 and .team == "Payments").id)'
```

Output:

```
["54321", "12345", "123456", "1234567"]
```

Below is the second command that given a specific employee **ID**, returns the **years** they've worked at their **primary office** **in-state** and whether they're **open** to remote work:

```
zcat addresses.gz | grep 12345 | jq '[.openToRemoteWork, .workHistoryInState.primaryOffice.address.YEARSSPENT]' -c
```

Output:

```
[no,19]
```

I'm missing the final command which ties everything together which will basically run the second command for each id returned by the first command, and then filter the output by checking whether that employee is open to work and has the most years spent working at their in-state primary state compared to any other employee in the list, and then return that employee's ID at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do all of this in just one jq call. Load one file with `-s` or `--slurp` (as you already do), and the other one with `--slurpfile` to have it accessible as a variable. Then, use `JOIN` to combine by their IDs (one is a number, the other one a string, so use `tostring` or string interpolation `"\()"` to convert). Finally, employ `max_by` to filter by your "most years" criteria, and output the ID:

```bash
zcat employees.gz | jq --slurpfile a <(zcat addresses.gz) -s '
  map(select(.age > 25 and .team == "Payments"))
  | JOIN(INDEX($a[]; .id); "\(.id)")
  | map(.[1] | select(.openToRemoteWork == "yes"))
  | max_by(.workHistoryInState.primaryOffice).id
'
```

```json
"54321"
```

Note: Use the `-r` (or `--raw-output`) option to have a raw text output (`54321`) instead of a JSON string (`"54321"`).